# Getting facebook groups posts with Graph API

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts

I am trying to understand whether it is possible to read posts of groups in which I am a member (but not an admin) with facebook graph api? I understand facebook changed their API policy so it is now more strict but I find it hard to believe that they wouldn't allow something so basic and couldn't find a clear answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api ? Under Requirements it lists what is required.